# How to do JEE EJB Dependency Injection with Kotlin

Tags: dependency-injection, kotlin, ejb-3.1

I have converted a REST resource in a JEE application formally written in Java to Kotlin. The application runs in a Wildfly Application Server with Weld as Dependency Injection framework.

This is the final implementation I came up with:

```
@Path("/myResource")
open class MyResource {

  @Context
  private lateinit var context: SecurityContext

  open protected setSecurityContext(securityContext: SecurityContext) {
    this.context = securityContext
  }

  @POST
  @Path("/change")
  @Transactional
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  open internal fun change(data: MyChangeData, @Context uriInfo: UriInfo): Response {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The setter is for testing purposes. With Mockito or other mocking frameworks that can set private fields this is not neccessary.

I had some issues with this implementation:

1. I had to change the class and all methods to `open` to allow the CDI Container to create a proxy for this bean. As I understand this topic there is no other way to allow Weld to do its work without allowing subclassing?
2. Generally Kotlin generates setters and getters for properties with the given modifier (public/private/protected) backed by a private field. But when using `lateinit` the field is generated with the same visibility as the getters and setters (Kotlin in Action, p. 146). I don't understand the background for this special behaviour. Using `public` property causes an error in Weld reporting that public fields are not allowed. How can I declare that the field should be private but the getter and setter is protected (to initialize the Resource in tests)?
3. What is annotated in the code above? The field or the generated methods? If it is the field: How can I annotate the setter only?
4. Because all methods but private ones have to be `open` all properties but private ones are rejected by the Weld container: Kotlin creates Getters and Setters with the same visibility and the container tries to proxy the bean proxying all methods for the bean. This does not work because the generated getters and setters are not `open`. For private properties there simply is no problem because the container does not proxy private methods. As I see there is no possibility to declare a getter/setter as `open` therefor it is not possible to use protected properties

EDIT: Added Ploblem 4 and changed the Implementation because of this problem to private with a setter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I could find is to declare the property as `open protected`:

```
@Context
open protected lateinit var context: SecurityContext
```

This way the container can override it and tests from java or groovy will see the setter as package protected.

If you want to annotate the setter only (which I would prefer but is more verbose) you can use:

```
open protected lateinit var context: SecurityContext @Context set
```

or better and shorter:

```
@set:Context
open protected lateinit var context: SecurityContext
```

Unfortunately this will not work with Kotlin tests because `protected` vars can only be seen by subclasses in Kotlin. Here you have to write a seperate accessor:

```
@Context
open protected lateinit var context: SecurityContext

open internal fun setTheSecurityContext(context: SecurityContext) ...
```

Or you can use a secondary constructor:

```
open class MyResource() {

constructor(context: SecurityContext): this() {
  this.context = context
}
```

Note that the primary empty constructor has to be still present.

And here are the separate answers for my questions:

1. If the dependency injection framework uses proxys `open` is necessary for the class and every method and property (but `private` ones).
2. No. With `lateinit` the property has the same visibility as the getters and setters. If you want to do this you have to declare the property as nullable. But then you have to use `!!` on every access which is awkward.
3. The field. As seen above you can write `@Context set` or `@set:Context` to annotate the setter.
4. As stated in 1 all properties but private ones have to be declared as open.

EDIT: Note that private properties also cause problems (tested with Wildfly). My recommendation is not to use private at all but protected.

EDIT 2: Note that these workarounds are only necessary on an EJB (like a REST-Resource). With simple CDI Beans this is no proplem until they are proxied by an aspect or such. Then this post would also apply.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes
2. I don't know background too, but you can workarond that by changing code to smth like

`open class A {
     @Context
     private lateinit var _backing: SecurityContext
     open protected var field: SecurityContext
       get() = _backing
       set(value) { _backing = value }
}`

Also, you can use constructor injection

3. You're annotating field there. To annotate getters/setter you can add `@get:` and `@set:` to annotations.

Comment: The code above produces a compiler error "Setter visibility must be less permissive than property visibility". Seems as you cannot declare the setter or getter public and the field private.

Comment: Constructor injection is not permitted here because a REST resource is an EJB and has to have an empty default constructor.

Comment: @MarcvonRenteln updated my answer with another pattern with backing field. Will that work for you?

Comment: Sadly no, because of another problem that I have discovered after my first post. I have added a description of the problem as 4. and changed the implementation. The second field that you created would be rejected by the container. The solution I created is similar but uses an open function.

Comment: @MarcvonRenteln what if you add open to get() and set()?

Comment: The compiler did not allow that... ("Open is not applicable to setter")

Comment: @MarcvonRenteln I'm sorry. Of course `var` (`field` in my case) should be open

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163735/discussion-between-asm0dey-and-marc-von-renteln).